# Azure AD B2C Validate Claim value inside custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Are in B2C Custom Policies a way to validate claims comparing them?
Lets say we need to validate the user postal code to reset a password, can we do:
`insertedPostalCode == actualPostalCode` 
( compare two claims ).
Of course, this is after reading the user from B2C using a email, or some other signin name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely do this.

I'm going to assume you're using B2C custom policies.

Use a claims transformation, either the AssertStringClaimsAreEqual, or the CompareClaims, in a technical profile that can be added as a validation step in the self asserted page you are using to collect this postal code from the user.

Here are the Microsoft docs that should point you in the right direction.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#assertstringclaimsareequal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#compareclaims